# Concat/Union Tables in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This current project is more of a proof of concept for a larger project. I have two "tables" (represented as lists below), `CatList` and `DogList`, that have identical column structure. I wish to be able to `Concat` or `Union` the two and perform a query on the resulting set using `LINQ`. I was told that by implementing `interfaces` I would be able to achieve these results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.Write("Hello World\n");
        Dog Dog1 = new Dog { name = "A", age = 1 };
        Dog Dog2 = new Dog { name = "B", age = 2 };
        Cat Cat1 = new Cat { name = "C", age = 3 };
        Cat Cat2 = new Cat { name = "D", age = 4 };

        List<Dog> DogList = new List<Dog>();
        List<Cat> CatList = new List<Cat>();
        DogList.Add(Dog1);
        DogList.Add(Dog2);
        CatList.Add(Cat1);
        CatList.Add(Cat2);

        var result = DogList
                .Concat(CatList);

    }
}

public interface iAnimal
{
    string name { get; set; }
    int age { get; set; }
}
public class Dog :iAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
public class Cat:iAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I can access any of the data members of any of my created objects using something like `System.Console.Write(Dog1.name);`, so I THINK my implementation of interfaces is correct. What needs to be changed in my LINQ statement in order to effectively Concat/Union my lists.

I am rather new to `C#` and object oriented programming in general, so please cater your answers to suit my knowledge level.

Thanks

**EDIT**
I apologize, as I have forgotten to include the error message I get in my current code.

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.List<InterfaceTest.Dog>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Concat<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<InterfaceTest.Dog>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<InterfaceTest.Cat>'
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include errors. The question is fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler can't figure out that by concatenating a `List<Dog>` and a `List<Cat>` it should produce a collection of `iAnimal`s. By default it sees a `List<Dog>` and expects the following collection to be a collection of `Dog` too.

You can explicitly tell to treat everything as an `iAnimal` this by providing the generic parameter to `Concat`, i.e.

```
var result = DogList.Concat<iAnimal>(CatList);
```

You then get a `result` of type `IEnumerable<iAnimal>`.

Edit: If you're stuck on .NET 3.5, you'll need something like

```
var result = DogList.Cast<IAnimal>().Concat(CatList.Cast<IAnimal>());
```

as 3.5 can't automatically convert `collection of something that inherits iAnimal` to `collection of iAnimal`.

Comment: Note that this requires C# 4 for covariance support.

Comment: Oh, really? Thanks Jon. (I've apparently managed to accept covariance and not notice when I'm using it.)

Comment: This solved my problem (+1), but interestingly, the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397914.aspx) seem to suggest you can `Concat` two objects without this technique and even when they don't share a common inheritance

Comment: @Bob The only use of `Concat` on that page is between two `IEnumerable<string>` objects.

Comment: @Rawling Yep - absolutely right... thought I must have missed something!

Answer (score 3):

The generic lists are from different types (Dog and Cat), you have to "cast" them to the target interface before concatenation:

```
var list1 = DogList.Cast<IAnimal>();
var list2 = CatList.Cast<IAnimal>();

var bothLists = list1.Concat(list2); //optional .ToList()
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it looks like it should work considering it just uses `List` extension methods. I was looking for a `LINQ` solution as this is simply a proof of concept project for a larger one.

Comment: @Jeff `Cast` is a LINQ method, not a `List` method.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Disregard my comment.