# Using interfaces in LINQ database queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on part of an application that simply pulls information from the database and displays it to users. For simplicity sake, let us assume I have a database with two tables, `Cats` and `Dogs`. Both tables have manually assigned primary keys and are **never** duplicated/overlapped. The goal I am trying to achieve is to perform 1 LINQ query that will `concat` both tables.

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219880/concat-union-tables-in-linq) question regarding performing a `LINQ concat` on two collections of objects, `Cats` and `Dogs`, that were manually created in code. I advise reading the previous question as it will give much insight to this one.

The reason I wish to use interfaces is to simplify my queries. I currently have a solution that `.Select` each of the columns I need into an anonymous type. This would work fine for this instance, but will consume pages with the data I am working with.

The different between that previous question and this one is that I am trying to pull these animals from a database. From my analysis, it seems that `.NET` or `Entity Framework` is not able to relate my `database` to my `interface`

**Model** (From old question)

```
public interface iAnimal
{
    string name { get; set; }
    int age { get; set; }
}
public class Dog :iAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
public class Cat:iAnimal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Here are some different `LINQ` queries I have tried and the resulting error. The first example will be using the solution from the previous question.

```
var model = _db.Cats.Concat<iAnimal>(_db.Dogs).Take(4);

System.ArgumentException: DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes.
```

Without Covariance:

```
var model = _db.Cats.Cast<iAnimal>().Concat(_db.Dogs.Cast<iAnimal>());

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'Test.Models.Cat' to type 'Test.Interfaces.iAnimals'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
```

From the above error, it looks like I am not able to use interfaces to interact with databases as it is not mapped to any particular table.

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**
In response to @Reed Copsey, with your solution, I get the same error as my example `without covariance`. I tried changing the view's type to match what the error recommends, which results in this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Test.Interfaces.iAnimal]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test.Models.Cat]'.
```

Comment: When you concat them together, how is it able to tell which `iAnimal` references which datasource? Can you do this in SQL itself and be able to differentiate the two sources? In other words, if you did `SELECT ID, Name, Age FROM Dogs UNION SELECT ID, Name, Age FROM Cats` and you only looked at the result set, would you be able to differentiate the source for each record?

Comment: In NHibernate, you can use inheritance only if you define a discriminator. Maybe Entity have a similar requirement.

Comment: There is no requirement for such behavior on this page. It is strictly read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You database knows nothing about your interface and you will probably not be able to get this working. I see two options.

You could use inheritance - for example supported by the Entity Framework - and inherit both entities from a common base entity. Than you will be able to perform queries against the base type but this may require changes to your data model depending on the way you implement inheritance at the database level.

Have a look at the documentation for [TPT inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293) and [TPH inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292). There are still other inheritance models like TPC inheritance but they currently lack designer support.

The second option is to fetch results from both tables into memory and use LINQ to Objects to merge them into a single collection.

```
var dogs = database.Dogs.Take(4).ToList();
var cats = database.Cats.Take(4).ToList();

var pets = dogs.Cast<IPet>().Concat(cats).ToList();
```

Also note that your query

```
var model = _db.Cats.Concat<iAnimal>(_db.Dogs).Take(4);
```

seems not really well designed - the result will definitely depend on the database used but I would not be surprised if you usually just get the first four cats and never see any dog.

Comment: I believe I tried this, but it didn't work. I'll try again... Stay tuned. The query I wrote was more of a proof of concept. I didn't want 1000+ items being returned. I just wanted to test for functionality of `.Concat` first.

Comment: This solution works, but what if the dataset is large? If I recall, `ToList()` is a greedy operator. This solution would run the two queries. Would it be possible to manipulate this to only touch the database once?

Comment: This may be neither here nor there, but I'm not totally seeing how this (not just this answer, but the use of an interface in this scenario in general) simplifies or otherwise eases what would otherwise be `var query = db.Cats.Concat(db.Dogs)`.

Comment: I am quite sure it is not possible to merge both queries into one unless you use inheritance. Do you really need a single query? I can not think of many cases where this would make any difference. If you want 100 pets, just try to get 100 dogs and if there are less than that fetch `100 - number-of-dogs-returned` cats. If you want a list of the 100 youngest pets than things become harder - you do not know how many cats and dogs to fetch. But you could still fetch the 100 youngest cats and 100 youngest dogs and merge them in your application - overhead of factor two, not to bad.

Comment: `var query = db.Cats.Concat(db.Dogs)` will just not work unless you modeled both entities using inheritance. If you do this, you can just query `db.Pets`, `db.Pets.OfType<Cat>()` and `db.Pets.OfType<Dog>()`.

Comment: Perhaps inheritance is the better solution in this scenario. I will attempt to implement a sample of this. If you could update your solution to show an inheritance solution, that would be helpful as I am sadly new to object oriented programming.

Comment: Have a look at the two links to TPT and TPH inheritance, they provide a step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: Inheritance works fine in `c#`, but my model classes already inherit from my `Database` class. It seems the language does not allow for multiple base classes, but multiple interfaces is okay.

Comment: What model are you using? Code first?

Comment: Database first (If that's the correct terminology). The database is owned by my group, but not these tables I am working on in particular. My database class is pretty much full of these: `public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }` and `modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().ToTable("Activity", "SomeSchema");`

Comment: Code first: You just write some classes, the database already exists or is generated from the classes you have written. Database first: The database already exists and code is generated for all entities. Model first: You build a model using the Entity Framework designer and the database and code for all entities are generated based on the model.

Comment: I wrote classes that matched my existing database, so I suppose code first, by your definition

Comment: Then this article and the other two parts linked in the article should get you started. TPC might be the easiest way to go for you. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Comment: It looks like I must have followed the wrong tutorial a while back (or maybe it changed from MVC3 - MVC4?). In the context of [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model) well documented example, my `Movie` class would have started with `public class Movie : MovieDBContext`. Looks like my application works without that inheritance.

Comment: That is correct - there is no need that your entity classes inherit from your database context and it never was a requirement in any Entity Framework version. If you look at the linked article again you will see that it does not suggest this, too. The only inheritance mentioned is `public class MovieDBContext : DbContext { [...] }` and this one is required.

Comment: Looks like things work. If you want to edit your answer with what we talked about in the comments, I will gladly mark this as the answer.