# Deciding on T of Linq.Table<T> at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two identically structured tables which exist in two separate databases. Both database objects inherit the DataContext class and share a common interface, as does each table in the database. The problem is that the Linq.Table class expects a class as T but I need it to be an interface in order to determine the correct table at runtime. Below is some code that I hope will explain the issue

The common interface that both database objects share

```
interface ICommonDataContext
{
    // Table <T> where T is a class 
    Table<ITable1> Table1 { get; }
}
```

An example of a common interface that the same table in both databases share

```
public interface Table1
{
    int Col1 { get; set; }
    int Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

The autogenerated Region1DataContext code with interface implementation

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="MyDB")]
public partial class Region1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    #endregion

    public Region1DataContext() : 
            base(ConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public Region1DataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public Region1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public Region1DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public Region1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<ITable1> Table1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<ITable1>();
        }
    }
}
```

The Table1 code with interface implementation

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="Table1")]
public partial class Table1
{
    private int _Col1;
    private int _Col2;

    public Table1()
    {
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Col1", DbType="Int")]
    public int Col1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Col1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Col1 != value))
            {
                this._Col1 = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Col2", DbType="Int")]
    public int Col2
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Col2;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Col2 != value))
            {
                this._Col2 = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other partial classes declarations, including the interface implementation

```
{
    public partial class Region1DataContext : ICommonDataContext { }
    public partial class Table1 : ITable1 { }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer will show some guide to solve your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222723/using-interfaces-in-linq-database-queries

Comment: Why not just add a parameter to indicate the database?  You already know which database is connected since the connection string is different.  So simply pass the database name to the routine instead of doing it dynamically.  You could also get the database name from the connection property.

Comment: Add a parameter where?